# multidimensional array in angular have issue

Tags: php, angularjs, multidimensional-array

What is the issue in my code?

return array is

```
{"records":
    [{"Status":"1",
    "Date":"2017-07-14 10:46:33",
    "Email":"cy@gmail.com","Company":"Inc.",
    "Model":"Model 8081 A","Animation":"Walk, Turn Around","id":"1",
    "Note":"This is a new request for model with animation.",
    "Attachment":
        "[{'url':'request/31a.jpg','name':'a.jpg'},{'url':'request/42Light.png','name':'Light.png'}]"
}]
}
```

And HTML code is

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
    <td>{{x.Status}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Date}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Email}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Company}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Model}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Animation}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Note}}</td>
    <td>
        <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="lnk in x.Attachment">
            <td>{{lnk.url}}</td>
            <td>{{lnk.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>          
</tr>
```

`lnk.url` and `lnk.name` print nothing.

> Error in console is  [ngRepeat:dupes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attachment` is a string not an array. convert it to an array and it will l work

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  
   $scope.records = [  
      {  
         "Status":"1",
         "Date":"2017-07-14 10:46:33",
         "Email":"cy@gmail.com",
         "Company":"Inc.",
         "Model":"Model 8081 A",
         "Animation":"Walk, Turn Around",
         "id":"1",
         "Note":"This is a new request for model with animation.",
         "Attachment":[{'url':'request/31a.jpg','name':'a.jpg'},{'url':'request/42Light.png','name':'Light.png'}]
      }
   ] 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
    <td>{{x.Status}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Date}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Email}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Company}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Model}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Animation}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Note}}</td>
    <td>
        <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="lnk in x.Attachment">
            <td>{{lnk.url}}</td>
            <td>{{lnk.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>          
</tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I get this string from url

Comment: angular.module("requestModel", [])
   .controller("requestCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
       $http.get("all_request").then(function(response) {
        $scope.values = response.data.records;
        
    });
   });

Comment: @Deepak3301086 nice. make sure to check as answer if this helped

Answer (score 2):

Your attachment is not an array, it is a string. Your return array should be like this:

```
{
  "records": [{
    "Status": "1",
    "Date": "2017-07-14 10:46:33",
    "Email": "cy@gmail.com",
    "Company": "Inc.",
    "Model": "Model 8081 A",
    "Animation": "Walk, Turn Around",
    "id": "1",
    "Note": "This is a new request for model with animation.",
    "Attachment": [{
        "url": "request/31a.jpg",
        "name": "a.jpg"
    }, {
        "url": "request/42Light.png",
        "name": "Light.png"
    }]
  }]
}
```

(Notice removed quotes in Attachment).

So you should convert Attachment with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but if i remove quotes in attachment then all code is not working. means first ng-repeate also not work

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single. Single quotes are not considered as valid JSON. I have edited my answer